# Rewriting URI within Nginx

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

Im trying to get URI Routing set up for my framework and im currently working on nginx as teh server, but the problem is i keep getting 500 error when trying to access either one of the following links

- `http://localhost.framework/`
- `http://localhost.framework/index.php/`

If I access the site using the following links it works:

- `http://localhost.framework/index.php`
- `http://localhost.framework/index.php?/`

my configuration for the domain is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost.framework;
    root   /var/www/ASFramework;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/framework.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/framework.error.log;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/ASFramework$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

basically what im trying to do is take the following url

- `http://localhost.framework/controller/method/../`

and rewrite it to:

- `http://localhost.framework/index.php/controller/method/../`

Within the logs `(error.log)` is:

```
2011/07/03 22:57:22 [error] 19837#0: *6 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost.framework, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost.framework"
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

into this:

```
location ~ \.php.*$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/ASFramework$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your rewrite rule causes redirection cycle. *nginx* substitutes `index.php` with `index.php/index.php` recursively. So after second replacement your new URL will be `index.php/index.php/index.php` and so on.

You probably want something like this:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/index.php\?action=(.*)$ /$1 last;
}
```

Which rewrites `index.php?action=someaction` to `/someaction`.

Comment: this is not how the framework works, the framework will take the whole URI i.e `index.php/controller/method/param` => `/controller.method/param` and then use that as the route, this is perfectly possible in Apache and Lighttpb, i need to take the `http://host/controller/method/param` and cat everything after the first `/` and pass it to `index.php/$1`

Comment: Yea I updated a short while ago, thanks for the effort though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location / {
    if ($request_uri !~ "/(index\.php)") {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }
}
```